# Python not recognizing global variables

Tags: python, python-2.7, ide

I have a module I've been using for some time with global variables initialized outside of  a function, such as:

```
myVar = 1

def fnPrintMyVar():
    print myVar
```

Today I was debugging and the interpreter suddenly stopped recognizing the global variables, yielding the familiar, *NameError: global name 'myVar' is not defined* in the console.

I ran it in WingIDE and stopped the code just before the print line.  The IDE showed myVar correctly in the watch list, but when I tried to run the print line it raised the same exception.

As a temporary workaround, I put all my globals inside another function as below:

```
def fnVarHolder():
    global myVar
    myVar = 1

def fnPrintMyVar():
    global myVar
    print myVar
```

This worked for a while, then stopped working in the same way as suddenly as the first method.  I have tried closing down everything, including resetting the system, but the exception is still raised.  I assume there's a non-volatile file somewhere causing this, but I have no idea where to look.  Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As for "non-volatile files somewhere" try deleting directories called `__pycache__` and any `*.pyo` and `*.pyc` files.

Hope this helps, but since this sounds like a problem that is local to your computer it's hard to reproduce.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I must have missed a couple reloads during debug and misdiagnosed what was happening.  Including the global line in the function where the variable was used was the right method.